# What would happen if lightning couldn't strike the ground due to a layer of unconductive gas?

Tags: atmosphere, weather, lightning

My world has an upper atmosphere similar to Earth's, and a lower atmosphere compromised of Sulfur Hexafluoride and water. In between is a layer of clouds. Massive treelike sulfite structures stretch to all three layers of the atmosphere.

The bottom layer of the atmosphere is very hot since SF6 is a powerful greenhouse gas, so the water here is gaseous. As far as I'm aware, Sulfur Hexafluoride is NOT conductive, so **what would happen to the building static charge?**

Comment: Gas on Earth isn't conductive either. Plasma is however.  Are you needing to know the breakdown voltage at a certain temp and pressure?

Comment: I don't think so, I just needed to know if there'd be a drastic change in how lightning behaved. Thanks though

Comment: Hey Grant! You wrote a good question that sufficiently covered the bases needed for a good answer. In future, if you're still unsure about your question writing skills, slide on over to our Meta forum where we have a Sand Box where you can get help with question formulation!

Comment: Normal air is not conductive. In fact it is a very good insulator; that's why we can use 400 kilovolt overhead power lines with no problems. But. When subjected to sufficiently strong electric fields [insulators break down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_breakdown). Normal air has a breakdown strength of about 30,000 volts per centimeter, or about 75,000 volts per inch. Sulfur hexafluoride is much better, with a breakdown strength of about 90,000 volts per centimeter or so. The point is that even SF6 *will* break down when sufficient voltage is applied.

Comment: I'd like to know where your planet got all of that fluorine, but that would be a digression...

Comment: Is there such thing as unconductive?

Comment: Actually, the more unconductive a material is, the more charge it can accumulate. Until it breaks down as others explain. So the lightning will be stronger.

Comment: And the corollary: if air was normally conductive, there would never be any lightning, because the charges would immediately equalize.

Comment: Since on earth lightning requires ice particles in the air, one might ask if this planet would even have any lightning with such a hot atmosphere. Or lightning might happen only high in the atmosphere and nowhere close to the Sulfur Hexafluoride layer.

Answer (score 21):

Sulfur Hexafluoride may not be conductive under normal circumstances, but subject it to a sufficiently high voltage differential, and like any other gas, including those in *our* atmosphere, it will become ionised, and its electrical resistance will drop significantly, allowing a bolt of lightning to pass through it regardless.

However, the presence of the 'Massive treelike sulfite structures' that 'stretch to all three layers of the atmosphere' may provide an alternative path for lightning, depending upon the relative conductivity of the atmospheric gases and the sulphite tree-structures.  The lightning will follow the path of least electrical resistance.  That usually means that lightning travels to the nearest solid object.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Would there be more buildup before discharge in this world as opposed to Earth?

Comment: @GrantCory You could look up - or ask about - the relative ionisation energy of our atmospheric gases (N2 & O2) and SF6.  If SF6 has higher ionisation energy, then the lightning voltages must be higher.

Comment: @GrantCory: Normal air dielectric breakdown strength is about 30 kV/cm. Sulfur hexafluoride breakdown strength is about 90 kV/cm. In normal air a thunderbolt strikes when the voltage difference reaches about 300 MV; with a sulfur hexafluoride atmosphere, that would be some 1.2 GV, maybe more.

Comment: @GrantCory you will probably get cloud-to-cloud lightning long before any cloud-to-ground lightning can make it through the SF6.

Comment: @AlexP:  So with 4 times the voltage, if capacitance is similar to on our planet, that also means 4 times the stored charge, so 16 times the energy for a single lightning bolt, all else equal.  (Capacitor energy scales with `V^2 * C`).

Comment: Just *how* non-conductive are the sulphite trees?  You wouldn't get lightning at all if charge can leak down fast enough that the voltage never reaches the breakdown point of the gases or the trees.

Answer (score 9):

Lightning happens when a charge is built between two locations to the point where the gas in between breaks down. In order to have lightning, there needs to be a way to generate a charge separation. On Earth, that happens due to wind generating static electricity as hot air near the surface is drawn up into the clouds. A key point is the ionization around ice particles. https://www.noaa.gov/jetstream/lightning/how-lightning-is-created

Lightning happens between the two places of charge. It can happen within a cloud (and is quite pretty on a dark night). It can happen between a cloud and the ground. It can happen between a cloud and the upper atmosphere (sprites).

The first question has to be how to generate a separation of charge that involves the sulfurous lower atmosphere. Sulfur Hexafluoride is inert and is poorly soluble in water (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur_hexafluoride) and is considerably heavier than air or water vapor. That means that you will have very little mixing. Sulfur Hexafluoride is used as an electrical insulator and can insulate the ground from cloud electrical interactions.

It is very likely that this world will not have any lightning that would involve the Sulfur Hexafluoride. The lightning will stay up in the clouds.

If this planet had other sulfur compounds in the air, then there might be lightning interactions such as happen on Venus. https://www.nasa.gov/vision/universe/solarsystem/venus-20071128.html

Answer (score 6):

### *Air* is not conductive

The visible part of lightning is the superheated plasma you get when a sufficiently large voltage causes the air  (primarily Nitrogen) to break down into a plasma. Sulphur Hexafluoride will also break down under sufficiently large voltage.

Strangely, both air (understandable) and sulphur hexafluoride (weird) are in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_strength) very short Wikipedia list. Air has a dielectric strength of 3 MV/m3; sulphur hexafluoride is 8.5-9.8 or roughly three times higher.

In any event, more than 90% of lightning is cloud to cloud, not cloud to Earth. If your clouds are above the SF<sub>6</sub> layer, the lighting strikes to the ground will be substantially reduced.

Also, lightning is just a rapid discharge of static charge. Before the lightning, the cloud held a charge; if the lightning doesn’t happen … the cloud holds a charge. It will either rise until it overcomes the dielectric breakdown potential of the gas or it dissipates non-rapidly.